# How to avoid layout shift with multi-column text?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I use `column-width` to produce a multi-column text block on wider screens. However, this multi-column text block causes a large CLS (cumulative layout shift) of about 0.1s for Desktop view on the PageSpeed Insight tool. Example webpage is https://www.lybrary.com/aldo-colombini-m-45.html

If I remove the multi-column style CLS is zero. I have tried to apply that style directly to the element with a 'style' parameter, but this did not change anything. It doesn't matter if the style is applied through a style sheet, a style block in the HTML, or a style parameter in the element. When it is multi-column there is a large CLS reported. I don't understand why this is the case. Are multi-columns processed at the very end and thus they cause layout shifts? Any ideas of how to avoid this and still have responsive multi-column text that is a single column on smaller screens and a double column on wider screens?

Here is an example stripped down to a minimum. I am still seeing a 0.059 CLS on PageSpeed Insights:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mcol2 {
    column-width: 36em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article class=mcol2><p>(19th March 1951 - 12th February 2014)<p>
Aldo Colombini moved to the United States from Italy in 1993. He has performed in over 45 countries. He is a F.I.S.M. prizewinner. He performed often on Italian television (RAI 1) and has also appeared on television shows in Portugal, Spain, Japan, Colombia and Sweden.
<p>
Aldo has performed often at Caesar’s Magical Empire in Caesar’s Palace, Las Vegas and continues to appear several times a year at the famous Magic Castle in Hollywood, California where he is one of few magicians who are able to perform in all four showrooms. Aldo was voted by the Academy of Magical Arts, Hollywood, California: twice Parlor magician of the year. In the history of the Magic Castle is the only magician to be nominated in all five categories: Comedy, Stage, Close-up, Parlor and Lecturer. He appeared on “Masters of Illusion,” a series of weekly magic specials airing on PAX-TV. He speaks Italian, English, Spanish and French and can perform in all four languages allowing him to dazzle audiences from diverse backgrounds.
<p>
Aldo has written and published several books on magic and created many magical effects used by magicians all over the world. He also lectures on magic worldwide and was nominated by the Academy of Magical Arts twice Lecturer of the Year.<p>set alert for this author</p></article>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hi @Chris! Would you mind including necessary code to reproduce the issue? Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I have added HTML/CSS example code to my question.